# How do I change the image in a navbar based on what the active url is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is have `#navbar-image-id2games` be toggled when the active url is `index.html`. I attempted to do this with javascript like so, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar-item" id="navbar-item-ID2Games">
                            <a href="index.html" id="index-url">
                                <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-unhovered">
                                </div>
                                <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-id2games">
                                </div>

                                <br>

                                <div class="navbar-text">
                                    ID2 Games
                                </div>
                            </a>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#index-url').active(function() {
                  $('#navbar-image-id2games').toggle();
                  $('#navbar-image-unhovered').hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zxsmuaae/

Comment: No such function exists.  Look at the `location` object.

Comment: I believe he's trying to provide a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether or not the user is at `index.html` by doing:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/index\.html/)) {
    // toggle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the url with an `if` statement, and then set the visibility to hidden if it is on a certain page.

```
var navimg = document.getElementById("navbar-image-id2games");
if(window.location.href === "http://example/index.html"){
    navimg.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

If you want it to be reverse where it is hidden only when it is not on `index.html`, you can replace `===` with `!==`.